# What kind of argument is preferred to put in AlertDialog.Builder.setView()

Tags: android

I'm displaying a date picker using DialogFragment's onCreateDialog and i created a xml file for the date picker.

Should I:

1. setView directly with the R.layout.xml_name

   ```
   public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

           return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                   .setView(R.layout.dialog_date)           
                   .setTitle(R.string.date_picker_title)
                   .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,null)
                   .create();
   }
   ```
2. setView with a View object as argument, using LayoutInflater.inflate()

   ```
   public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())
                   .inflate(R.layout.dialog_date,null);

           return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                   .setView(v)
                   .setTitle(R.string.date_picker_title)
                   .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,null)
                   .create();
       }
   ```

Both display the same result, i saw option 2 in a book

is that just a different preference of using? which one is better practice?

Answer (score 1):

Both the things you mentioned do the exact same thing.

Internally, when you use `setView(int resourceId)`(your case 1), the Layout that you passed to the setView is `Inflated` internally and sent to `setView(View view)` function.

So, by using case 2, you're increasing your own work.

But, why use case 2 then? So, there are two kinds of context that you can pass to the

```
LayoutInflater.from(context)
```

Now, what does that mean?

1. If you pass the `Activity` context to the `LayoutInflater`, which will mean you'll be using the same theme applied to your activity in your AlertDialog.
2. But, if you use `getContext()`, as the documentation states:

> Note: To ensure consistent styling, the custom view should be inflated
>   or constructed using the alert dialog's themed context obtained via
>   getContext().

So, if you want consistency across all your dialog's, and if you've applied theme to your `AlertDialog`, it'll be applied to the dialog that you're inflating manually.

You can see more about [AlertDialog.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html) on the link.

Answer (score 0):

**Both are good in different situations -**

**Situation 1-** if you want simply to display a message then **option 1** is good because there is no extra effort is needed to inflate layout.

---

**Situation 2-**  if you want to perform some operation with the dialog then **option 2** is best.

**For Ex.-** Suppose you are using a **button to close the dialog** in your layout **dialog_date.xml** file than to perform an operation using that **button** you have to inflate **dialog_date.xml** to find the **id** of a button.

**like this-**

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())
                        .inflate(R.layout.dialog_date,null);
```

then

```
Button btnCloseDialog= v.findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
```

Comment: **option 2 is best for custom view dialog**

Comment: does that mean using layoutInflater provides more development flexibility in the future?

Comment: Yes, you are right using **LayoutInflater** you are not just limited to display a simple dialog. You can add any views to your layout and perform an operation according to your need just simply finding their **ids**.